# Shell Script-> use predefined username password for git prompt

Tags: bash, sh

I want to use predefined username and password stored in file and how to use it while committing in git repo which asks for username and password.

Comment: Does the git repo support ssh keys? They allow passwordless access.

Comment: Yes... but i am assuming that end user is not setup with ssh keys. I am assuming that end user enters username password manually. I just want to save it so that no more need to enter again at every commit push

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do this:

```
git remote set-url origin https://name:password@github.org/repo.git
```

Or use SSH instead of https (best)

```
git remote set-url origin git+ssh://git@github.com/username/reponame.git
```

Comment: I am going to try this.. just want to know when git push command asks for username and password is there any way to provide those details automacticall(say i saved those in text file and within shell script in variable)

Comment: You'd have to use expect